# QGIS reports that my .shp file does not have "Protocol" source type

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I tried to add my shapefile, but it reports this error:

```
Download with "Protocol" source type has failed, do you want to try the "File" source type?
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please expand on what exactly you did and when the error came up. Also describe, where the data is saved, what source it is from etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A shapefile consists of several files, of which .shp, .shx and .dbf are mandatory. These should be located in the same folder or in a zipped container. Open the shapefile by just dropping the .shp file or zipped container in the map frame, or use Ctrl+Shift+V.

Comment: I miss the .shx file. That might be the issue.

Answer (score 6):

When you try to add data on QGIS you could choose between different data type (File, Directory, Database and Protocol:HTTP(S),cloud,ect?)

The error you get state that the chosen "Protocol" source type has failed to load the data and suggest that you try the File source type.

As shapefile are of the file type you must choose File to be able to load it.

[image]