# shapefile is saved as AutoCAD type

Tags: qgis, shapefile, autocad

I'm asking this question for a student I have that can't open shapefiles in QGIS.

Whenever she tries to open shapefile in QGIS 3 she get this error message:

[image]

When I checked her library where the shapefile stored, I saw this:

[image]

these files, that on my computer are shapefile, on her computer are AutoCad.

This is how it looks in my computer:

[image]

My question is, how can I change it so she can load shapefiles into QGIS?

Comment: can she drag and drop the `.shp` file into the map window?

Comment: No, your question is, how can you teach her how to recognize the correct file to load (or teach her how the file browser in QGIS works) and how to use the correct program to load shape-files (not CAD). The error is fully on her side.

Comment: @Erik i'm used to ask questions for myself. ofcurse she will have to to it by herself, especially with the corona situation...but first I need also to understand it as I don't work with autocad

Comment: @IanTurton I would like to change the type in order not to have problems later. I don't know why she gets it as AutoCAD by deafult

Comment: @Reut this is a setting of her own PC. She needs to tell it "open `.shp` with QGIS - and not with CAD". Just rightclick the file and choose "open with". Or she should use the QGIS file browser. The error message simply says, that she tries to open the wrong file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the same as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339811/qgis-reports-that-my-shp-file-does-not-have-protocol-source-type/339820#339820) ie. you need to choose file and not protocol to open file based format like Shapefile.

As for the autocad thing it's just that autocad is installed on this specific computer and the system mistakenly recognize/attribute the extension for an autocad file and display that, it doesn't mean anything regarding the real format of the file (the system only look at the extension not at the content of file, I got the same false information on my computer but the Shapefile open fine)

Comment: I saw this post but she did chose file

Comment: @Reut the error message seem to imply that she did not choose file but protocol. if she did choose file and get this error it's probably a bug that need to be reported. Did she try to use the Data source manager (opposed to the add vector layer) to access the file and open from here ?

Comment: not sure I understood your question, she did use the data source manager